# Components are not being cleaned up on view change

Tags: ember.js

I have a route that for each item in the array it will create a component.

when I change route I can still see the component

components created ideas.index, if you click on one of the titles you will see the remnants of the last view still on the page

I couldn't recreate the error with a smaller JS bin so I have attached a zip, you can host it on a Apache server or change the script references

bit.ly/1aFGfjk

Comment: you are saying when I click on the title all the cards should disappear?

Comment: ye because its a different route to the ideas.index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last div tag isn't closed on the component :)

```
   </div
</script>
```

Additionally while I was going through it all I noticed a couple of other things.

1. components are agnostic of your app, so controllers.application in your component won't work
2. your CanvasView should be extending Ember.View.createWithMixins

Comment: thanks, silly mistake. thanks or the heads up on the components ill pass it as a prameter application=controllers.application.

Comment: as far as i remember i did, dunno why it didnt persist sorry